# Validation of viewstate MAC failed - Checkout form

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, dotnetnuke

I am creating a custom e-commerce system on DotNetNuke and c# asp.net 4.5.  The logic for my checkout process first checks if the user is a logged in customer or not, if not, it creates a user account from the form that was submitted and if that goes well, it logs the new account in and it then does the checkout.

If the checkout has errors, the form shows the error (like card declined).  This all works good, but as soon as I try another postback (like to change the shipping method) i get the 500 error : Validation of viewstate MAC failed  I assume this is because I am logging the user in during the process?  I have tried `enableViewStateMac="false"` in my web.config, but it does not help at all.

Any ideas on how I can avoid this type of error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by many different factors. Here is a [link to the Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;555353) about this issue.

What usually works for me is generating a machine key and adding it to the web.config. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221889/How-to-Generate-Machine-Key-in-IIS7) on how to do that.

Also, you really shouldn't be disabling viewstate mac, especially in an e-commerce application.